# cross join unnest multiple array columns in trino

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am learning Trino and one of the things I have encountered in `cross join unnest` when using arrays. However, when I try it with 2 columns, the results dont make much sense to me.

This is first example:

```
WITH dataset(department, users) AS (
    VALUES
        ('a', array[132,23,332]),
        ('d', array[10,20,30])
)
SELECT a.department, t.n AS channel_number, t.names FROM dataset a
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(users) WITH ORDINALITY as t(names,n)
```

this works fine, it explodes the dataset laterally and gives me three rows for each row.

Now, I add another column to it and try the same unnesting:

```
WITH dataset(department, users, attrs) AS (
    VALUES
        ('a', array[132,23,332], array['x','y','z']),
        ('d', array[10,20,30], array['k','q','l'])
)
SELECT a.department, t.n AS channel_number, t.names, x.nn AS channel_number2, x.atrs FROM dataset a
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(users) WITH ORDINALITY as t(names,n)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(attrs) WITH ORDINALITY as x(atrs,nn)
```

this seems to give me :

```
a 1 132 1 x
a 1 132 2 y
a 1 132 3 z
a 2 23 1 x
a 2 23 2 y
a 2 23 3 z
</snip>
```

However, I was looking for:

```
a 1 132 1 x
a 2 23 2 y
a 3 332 3 z
d 1 10 1 k
a 2 20 2 q
a 3 30 3 l
</snip>
```

Obviously there is something stupid which I am doing, but I am not able to figure out what it could be (trino newbie here)

Comment: With the second cross join it will take each value in that array and join it to each row or value of the previous array regardless of position in the array, which is what you are seeing.  If you only want the value from the second array that matches the same index of the first add a where clause `WHERE t.n = x.nn`

Answer (score 0):

Presto/Trino allows to unnest multiple array columns at a time (matching elements by index, filling missing values with `null`s if one array has less elements than the other, see the [example for `UNNEST` from the docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest)):

```sql
SELECT a.department, t.names, t.atrs 
FROM dataset a
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(users, attrs) as t(names, atrs)
```

Also note that a succinct syntax can be used:

```sql
SELECT a.department, t.names, t.atrs 
FROM dataset a
, UNNEST(users, attrs) as t(names, atrs)
```

ATM I don't have an instance available so not sure if it can be combined with the `WITH ORDINALITY` clause, but other than that this should do the trick.